# Where is the code for combo box plus check box in adempiere multiwindow?

Tags: java, swing, swingx, adempiere, swingbuilder

Where is the code for combo box plus check box in [adempiere](/questions/tagged/adempiere) multiwindow?
View the picture in the link. Where is the code for this in adempiere classes?
I have already checked on `APanel`, `VPanel`, `CPanel`, `AWindow`, `CTable`, `GridController`, `VInOutGen`, `VGenPanel`, `MiniTable`, etc. I couldn't find the appropriate code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[click to view code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K19ra.png)

Its helpful for mixed combobox n check box combination.

Answer (score 1):

This is functionality from SwingX (JXTable specifically) not Adempiere itself but it is utilized by Adempiere in the CTable class. Look at the CTable.ConfigureColumnControl() method and maybe google JXTable and "Column Control".

Comment: Thanx I got another method to do the same job.

Comment: Maybe you should share it so the next person with a similar problem can find the answer!